# jQuery drag&drop plugin not moving an element from its place - just making a copy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a test-page where people are supposed to drag&drop images to numbers. But it is necessary for images to stay at their original place but also being seen while dragging...
So I am looking for a jQuery plugin which would allow me to drag&drop elements by creating somehow a copy of the element while leaving the original element where it is. The copied&dragging element should dissappear:

a) was dropped on the right place

b) wasnt dropped on the right place

Both cases should end with an event saying "dropped" && "where was I dropped"

And suggestions ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI has the [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) and [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) interactions. Draggable has [the 'clone' helper](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper), which can be used to enable you to drag a clone of the item while the original remains in place.

Comment: @jave.web You can set it to revert back to its original location when dropped, which might be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: @jave.web Actually it does seem to be possible to have the original remain in place - check out the demo at http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart

Comment: lol I didnt find the shopping cart example - that is EXACTLY what I was looking for :) please add it to your answer :) thanks

Comment: @jave.web Have done. The 'clone' section is described at http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper - it's applied to the draggable, rather than the droppable.